# Microstrategy - filtering a dashboard depending on the user

Tags: filter, filtering, dashboard, microstrategy

I need to filter a dashboard basing on the user.

for example:

> if user1 my-attribute = 1
>
> if user2 my-attribute = 2

What method could I use for doing it also in reports and documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need here are the MicroStrategy Security Filters.

You can create two security filters, let call them:

> MyAttributeEqual1

and

> MyAttributeEqual2

Security Filters are pretty much similar to normal filters, so you can play with them and figure out the best condition you want to use.

Then you have to modify the users [to assign](http://www2.microstrategy.com/producthelp/9.5/WebAdmin/WebHelp/Lang_1033/Assign_security_filters.htm) the right filter.
In case you need you can assign Security Filters to a User Group and it will be applied to all users in that group.

Security filters will be added to the SQL code generate by MicroStrategy when you run a report and they will become an additional where condition.

A word of warning, be careful if you assign a security filter to an attribute and then you show data for a parent attribute, in that case the SQL engine will not apply the filter.